# How to display array data into tables in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display csv file data to frontend in reactjs. i read csv file using papaparse and i am getting all data

```
["0.122584", "0.785882", "0.954039", "0.353008"]
...
...
["0.122584", "0.785882", "0.886715", "-0.626392"]
```

and want to to display this array data in the form of table.

I tried this

```
class Panel extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={
          csvfile:undefined,
          data:null
      };

  }
  handleChange = event =>{
      this.setState({
          csvfile:event.target.files[0]
      });
  };

  importCSV = () =>{
      const { csvfile } = this.state;
      Papa.parse(csvfile, {
          complete: this.updateData,
          header: false
      });
  };

  updateData(result){
      var data = result.data;
      console.log(">>>>>")
      this.setState({
        data:data
      })
      console.log(data)
  }

render(){
return(
<Table bordered>
                 <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                     <th>First Name</th>
                     <th>Last Name</th>
                     <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <th scope="row">1</th>
                     <td>{this.state.data}</td>
                     <td>Otto</td>
                     <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
             </Table>
)
}
```

But it is not working well. it is displaying all data in single cell only.
i want each value in different cell.
I am a beginner in reactJs.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your data an array of object??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this can help you! I write two possibilities(tables) there because your question seems unclear to me.

> Update Code

```js
class Table extends React.Component{
 data = [
   ["0.122584", "0.785882", "0.954039", "0.353008"],
   ["1", "2", "0.954039", "0.353008"],
 ];
 render(){
   return(
       <table>
         <tbody>
           {
                this.data.map((numList,i) =>(
                   <tr key={i}>
                    {
                      numList.map((num,j)=>
                         <td key={j}>{num}</td>
                      )
                    }
                   </tr>
                ))
           }
         </tbody>
       </table>
   );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Table/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: hi hardik, i used above solution . i saved my data in state. and trying to get data in table by this.state.data.map.... getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null.

Comment: my data is look like this (4) [Array(6), Array(6), Array(6), Array(1)]
0: (6) ["r", "t", "t", "t", "tt", "t"]
1: (6) ["d", "df", "d", "d", "d", "d"]
2: (6) ["s", "hh", "hj", "s", "kk", "s"]

Comment: I updated the code. Please try it, hope it can help!

Comment: i add this !!this.state.data && this.state.data.map.... and works ....thanks hardik

Comment: it is giving one undefined row in the last of table

Comment: it is giving one undefined row in the last of table

Comment: i think some data should be missing there. in my demo i did not see anything wrong!

Answer (score 2):

You can map though you data and add a `<tr>` for each `this.state.data`.

```
//...your previous code

let tableRows = null;

if (this.state.data) {
  tableRows = <tr>
    {this.state.data.map((data, index) => {
      return (
        <td key={index}>
          {data}
        </td>
      );
    })}
  </tr>
}

return(
  <Table bordered>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {tableRows}
    </tbody>
  </Table>
```

)

Answer (score 1):

can you provide a snapshot of the data that should be displayed in a single row of your table? The Table component that you have posted has headers for First Name, Last Name, and Username. If the data is properly structured, then you can render it on the screen by modifying your component as follows:

```
  class Panel extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={
          csvfile:undefined,
          data:null
      };

  }
  handleChange = event =>{
      this.setState({
          csvfile:event.target.files[0]
      });
  };

  importCSV = () =>{
      const { csvfile } = this.state;
      Papa.parse(csvfile, {
          complete: this.updateData,
          header: false
      });
  };

  updateData(result){
      var data = result.data;
      console.log(">>>>>")
      this.setState({
        data:data
      })
      console.log(data)
  }

render(){
return(
<Table bordered>
                 <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                     <th>First Name</th>
                     <th>Last Name</th>
                     <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
{this.state.data.map((rowData, index) => (
                 <tr>
                     <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                     <td>{rowData.firstName}</td>
                     <td>{rowData.lastName}</td>
                     <td>{rowData.userName}</td>
                 </tr>

))}

                </tbody>
             </Table>
)
}
```

Here, I have made the assumption that your data for each row is an object with the properties `firstName`, `lastName`, and `userName`. Let me know if anything is unclear to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `<td>` element for each value in the `this.state.data` array, here is how you can do that:

```
<tr>
   ...
   { !!this.state.data && this.state.data.map(value => (<td>{value}</td>)) }
   ...
</tr>
```

Comment: i tried this but getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Comment: @chandra Oh, that is because `data` is `null` at first, I've edited my answer to address that.

Comment: it is somewhat working.. it is placing all elements of first array in first cell only. i want all elements of first array in first row, second elements array in second row.....and so on..  i after above solution i got affff,bgggt,cdddd.   but it should be like a  f  f  f   f then it second row b  g  g  gt....

Answer (score 0):

you can use antd :framework for reactjs
so you build columns in an easy way like this

```
const columns = [{
      title: 'First Name',
      dataIndex: 'first_name',
      sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],
      key: 'first_name',
      width: '20%',}]
```

and you can just :

```
return (

 <Table className="yourClassCss" columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} />

    );
```